# what are the information stored in strings we get after requesting cookies from a webpage while using python libraray called "requests"?

Tags: html, python-3.x, python-requests, browser-cache, ubuntu-18.04

Actually I was going through python library called `requests`. After making get request to a webpage and storing its response in an object called `r`; when I tried to see the cookies content of that object; I got string closed in `<..>` mainly containing random alphanumeric characters. I couldn't get or understand what information are hidden in that string.

```
import requests
r_object = requests.get('https://www.stackexchange.com/stories')
print (r_object.cookies)
```

Here is it's output:

```
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie prov=11531d97-98e5-3af7-2bdf-76e3edeece3e for .stackexchange.com/>]>
```

Comment: You're looking at an object, and that object presents itself in this particular way. It means it's a `RequestsCookieJar` object which contains a list of `Cookie` objects which contain the given values.

Comment: It says here that `RequestsCookieJar` acts like a `dict` with some extra methods. Have you seen that? https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar

Comment: @blueteeth no i had not seen that.At that time i was a beginner. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is:

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as s:
    resp = s.get("https://github.com")
    print(resp.cookies)
    # More details: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/cookies/
```

Result:

```
<RequestsCookieJar[
<Cookie logged_in=no for .github.com/>,
<Cookie _gh_sess=UHd5aUZ0ZXlBVDVPMitaVVBaWFp0c1p6dFA0TWVSanJzRGgrbU1XbVkxV3VXRW9LeWgwWHpWZ2pOOHFxZmtGaTZpRExpT2NjTHRyK3hHZG5GZjlxTzllbklqK0thQytHYi9HZWsrZ1poZ1ZUakJkRU9OZmJINEh3QUR2N3h3UUh6aVdFTmFCRHlHcVpwWHo1bEM5d25adnhUemJ6Y3pFMUxTbk50Q0M0UUJrVG5hR3kxRUVoUTB2TjdUc2hWbHk3cDJDWUZ4UW85NVRuR09keFJRTlc1QT09LS1RUnZHWUpsQ3BQU0hPZGtsWDAxQXFBPT0%3D--d2bd04e94c369f425fb7e9cc57b5b5499909b140 for github.com/>,
<Cookie has_recent_activity=1 for github.com/>]>
```

Please keep in mind that you've two other attributes which help you in handling cookies:

```
resp.cookies.items()
resp.cookies.get_dict()
```

Also it can be extracted by regex:
- [Example 1](https://regex101.com/r/yWnBB4/3)
- [Example 2](https://regex101.com/r/vU4jGz/1)

Here's an example:

```
import requests, re
with requests.Session() as s:
    resp = s.get("https://github.com")
    show_cookie = lambda x: [re.findall(r"([^,;\s]*?=.*?(?=;|$))|(\w+(?=;|$|,))",cookie) for cookie in re.findall(r"((?:^|,\s).*?)(?=,\s\S+;|$)",x)]
    print(show_cookie(resp.headers.get('Set-Cookie')))
[[('has_recent_activity=1', ''), ('path=/', ''), ('expires=Sat, 29 Dec 2018 14:43:45 -0000', '')], [('logged_in=no', ''), ('domain=.github.com', ''), ('path=/', ''), ('expires=Wed, 29 Dec 2038 13:43:45 -0000', ''), ('', 'secure'), ('', 'HttpOnly')], [('_gh_sess=eHBNWkZscHFMeXJ3NEJUU0VXZlBQaHg0S01rby9MK24xNnFvR3gvVTBsOUJjTWNWenJPZ0RRdk9RNE9ZV2V0MTQ1bTg2NEduY3phSWRrd3l0L252KzBJNkRYZlpjWXh5c2NBZktkWGFsdjZDbEJjTEdhVmZ0YnpldDFHTEpuQzFTcDNNS21sT3BRaHhBVUFqTHQ1cDZyQWNPU005ODY0bFh0MGxCbWI5d2kwait5RlcvVjlUc2FwTTdNRE8wOHZQb0RGak5YbG1ZSDJTM2ZpQmVUUkkrdz09LS11M0ZHem1YYjdWYkVLaWtRMkhscW5nPT0%3D--f778e2d24e96f3386a2da36e2d33d2b73418deed', ''), ('path=/', ''), ('', 'secure'), ('', 'HttpOnly')]]
```